# Redireccionar todas las rutas de una API REST al index

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hola sucede que estoy creando una API REST en PHP y no quiero usar un framework
 pero tengo el siguiente problema

Quiero crear un request por el método GET en el cual envie el ID de un producto para buscarlo en la base de datos.

Es decir:

```
http://localhost/ws_php/productos/1
```

el problema es que implemente un .htaccess  para que todas las solicitudes lleguen al index.php con el siguiente código que encontré en la web

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?url=$1&username=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

cuando imprimo la variable `$_GET['url'];` para buscar el ID que envié  solo me  aparece hasta "productos" sin el ID

Codigo de php

```
<?php  
    require_once('db.php');
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET"){
        $var = $_GET['url'];
        print_r($var);
    }else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
        echo" POST METHOD ";
    }else{
         http_response_code(405);
    }
?>
```

Todas las solicitudes van al index excepto las que apunte a la carpeta de imágenes

```
localhost/ws_php/img/miimagen.jpg
```

Comment: ¿Que URLs tienen que ir al index? ¿Y cuáles no? Me imagino que habrá imágenes en tu web que no se le llaman desde el index por ejemplo

Comment: cierto todas excepto las que  apunte a la carpeta de imagenes 

http://localhost/ws_php/img/miimagen.jpg

gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La expresión regular `^([^/]+)/?` sólo coincide con los primeros caracteres que no sean una `/`.

Si buscamos que todas las rutas que no existan vayan al index, por más que sean múltiples carpetas:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Si la ruta no es un archivo existente, ni una carpeta
# Reescribir al index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Si aún así, **todas** las rutas, incluso las existentes (imágenes por ejemplo) tienen que ir al index, creamos dos reglas: una para cuando se accede al index, que no procese más reglas; otra para que todo el resto vaya al index.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Si va al index, que no haga nada
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

# Y acá podemos agregar otras excepciones, por ejemplo la carpeta /img
RewriteRule ^img(?:/|$) - [L,NC]


# Reescribir al index todo el resto
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Gracias Crack. Solucionado